# How to stop firefox from switching to a new tab (show image)?

Tags: firefox, tabs

Firefox is killing me with this strange behaviour:

> Right click on image > Show image (click with middle button) > It
>   opens new Tab, but also switches to it.

WHY?
I did not find anything about that. Not even in the config. Why would I even want a new Tab, if I instantly want to review it? Is there a fix around that?

Can anyone tell me, how to stop this behaviour in firefox? Thank you.

Edit:
- Hint: No, this is not a web page behaviour, it happens on every page all the time. So do not say that.

Comment: If you've enabled "When opening a new tab, automatically switch to it" in Firefox options, then this will happen. Otherwise, the new tab will open in the background, but it will open a new tab anyway, unless the option to open in same tab exists in the contextual menu for the page, or image, you want to see later. That's up to the people who coded the page in question, not Mozilla's devs; that's why it'll also happen in Chrome, IE, any other browser. No one can stop you from taking a screenshot of your browser window if you can't download an image from a website, but copyright rules do exist..

Comment: See here (https://www.ghacks.net/2009/07/03/force-firefox-to-open-links-in-same-tab/) for how Firefox manages new tab/window opening, and here (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-same-tab/) for an extension that will enforce opening links in the same tab (may not be up-to-date, though).

Comment: Nope, this does not answer my question. I  have this deactivated, of course. It still directly switches to the new tab when opening an image.

Just try yourself like explained above:

Got to an image, right click and middle click on the entry "Show image" to open it in a new tab. I would wonder, if it does not insta switch to the new tab.

Comment: Like I said, the page is coded that way. It WILL open the image in a new tab or window, and you can't change that unless you go to about:config and change the parameter in browser.link.open_newwindow to set it to 1. (default is 3)

Comment: Please [edit] your questions and remove the rants.

Comment: No, Didier. It is not coded into the page. This happens all the time on any page. Or is every page, even my own page coded that way? I did not do that. Yet it does so.

Comment: I just tried myself in Firefox (Nightly, I might add), and right-click --> Show image doesn't open it in a new tab, it displays the image full-size in the middle of a dark background. The action by default for a left-click on an image in Firefox is to open a new tab leading to the website where the image comes from, but displaying only the image in the same tab is possible (at least on my copy of Firefox) via right-click. (That goes for images you search in your search engine of choice. Images embedded in other websites usually show as blown-up, with the website as background.)

Comment: Considering the responses to my answer attempt, it looks like you insist on a new core feature "open picture in background tab" (without using an addon). Only a [Mozilla developer](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Support#Development:_Bugs_and_Feature_Requests) can help with that.

Comment: I find it pretty annoying that Firefox switches to image tabs opened by using middle mouse button, but your question doesn't match your title. "Why would I even want a new Tab, if I instantly want to review it? Is there a fix around that?"

If you don't want a new tab don't use middle mouse button.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this can be changed. Probably you want the image not only displayed separately but also bigger. So if the addon [Imagus](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/imagus/) does not what you want, please edit the question to better describe what is your goal.
Nearer to your question
would be [another addon](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/8w33dk/open_images_in_background_tab_with_middle_click/).

Comment: not neccesary. I understand english good and maybe others can read it better that way.

The thing is, look at the now marked words. Just try for yourself. Firefox will open the image in a new tab. Yes, but it also switches to it instantly. Why would you need tabs, if you want to directly view it? Just loading it in the same window/tab would be sufficient, if I want that. I mean, pressing with the left mous button on "Show image" will open the image instantly and in the current tab. But if I want to open the picture in a new tab for *later* (!) use, I of course do not want it open instantly.

Comment: Okay nochmal auf deutsch:

Mit dem Mausrad auf "Grafik anzeigen" öffnet das Bild anstelle vom aktuellen Tab in einem neuen Tab. Das ist gewollt. Was nicht gewollt ist, dass er sofort in den neuen Tab wechselt. Das nervt, wenn man 10 Bilder in einem neuen Tab öffnen will - man muss dann jedes mal zurückswitchen. Das kostet Zeit und Nerven. Wie kann ich verhindern, dass er automtisch in den neuen Tab wechselt. Und probier es einfach mal selbst.

Comment: Ich will kein Addon außer Greasmonkey (Addons = zusätzliche Sicherheistlücken). Und zwei apps wurden empfohlen: Imagus - nach der Beschreibung ein Addon um durch hovern über einen Link ein Preview zu bekommen. Das passt 0 zu meinem Anliegen. Und das andere war nicht ersichtlich, weil "versteckt" hinter dem link "another addon". Und ich habe mich durchgerungen es zu installieren. "Open image in new tab" - Nur: Es funktioniert nicht. Jetzt habe ich also ein addon installiert, was möglicherweise ein backdoor gedroppt hat (wer weiß) und nicht den Zweck erfüllt. Deswegen keine zusätzlichen addons.

Comment: Ich bin im Bezug auf Sicherheit im Netz paranoid. Aber das ist nicht grundsätzlich schädlich. Die Frage ist: Nehmen die Leute, die das empfehlen selbst, oder ist es ein 5 minuten Google Ergebnis? Das ist, wie alle Leute, die heutzutage 50 Apps auf ihrem Handy installieren. Eine Seuche in meinen Augen und ein hohes Sicherheitsrisiko. Jede einzelne kann einen Bufferoverflow auslösen, wenn man Pech hat.

Comment: Zum Anwendungszweck: Ich habe das oft gemacht. Ich möchte die Bilder z.B. ohne Hyperlink angezeigt bekommen, es sind zeitgleich 10 Bilder auf der seite. Ich will nicht 10 mal rüber switchen. Beispiel: Arbeit mit Texturen. Weiteres Beispiel: Arbeit mit Stock Fotography. Es liegt an jedem selbst, ob er das maximal mögliche aus einem PC holen will. aber ich bin ein Mensch, der gerne 200 Tabs simultan auf hat und gleichzeitig noch überblickt. Daher musst du mich nicht zwingend in den Gründen verstehen. Danke dennoch für den Versuch.

Comment: Ich persönlich muss nicht - aber die Community hier sollte, damit sie dir ggf. eine alternative Antwort geben kann. Im Moment interpretierte ich den Anwenungsfall als "ansehen" - das ist eben auch mit z.B. erster Extension durch hovern ohne neuen Tab möglich. Die Extension für neuen Hintergrundtab wurde bei Reddit jedenfalls als Lösung markiert - somit was anderes als ein direktes Google-Ergebnis. Bitte dann den Mozilla Forum/Bugzilla Link in der Frage mit angeben.

Answer (score 0):

Using Shift + middle Mouse opens the image in a new background tab.